# Change width of Master of MasterDetailPage for android in xamarin-forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In xamarin-forms application, 
I want to change width of left side menu For android app.

I am try to change width as per below code

```
class MyMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DrawerWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyMasterDetailPage, int>(p => p.DrawerWidth, default(int));

    public int DrawerWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(DrawerWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DrawerWidthProperty, value); }
    }
    }
```

Now android app code.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailRenderer))]
class MyMasterDetailRenderer : MasterDetailRenderer
{
    bool firstDone;

    public override void AddView(View child)
    {
        if (firstDone)
        {
            MyMasterDetailPage page = (MyMasterDetailPage)this.Element;
            LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams)child.LayoutParameters;
            p.Width = page.DrawerWidth;
            base.AddView(child, p);
        }
        else
        {
            firstDone = true;
            base.AddView(child);
        }
    }        
}
```

above code is not working. 
Please share idea about How to change width of MasterDetailPage for android ap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided actually works, problem is that `this.Element` now is not exposed, usually we can get the instance of `MyMasterDetailPage` by overwriting the `OnElementChanged` method, problem is that `AddView` here is called earlier than `OnElementChanged`.

Currently I could't find an elegant way to define a `BindableProperty` in `MyMasterDetailPage` and get the value of this property in `AddView` event, but we can set it directly in renderer's code for example:

```
if (firstDone)
{
    LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams)child.LayoutParameters;
    p.Width = 300;
    base.AddView(child, p);
}
else
{
    firstDone = true;
    base.AddView(child);
}
```

If I can find a better solution here, I will come back to update this answer.

Comment: p.Width = 300 not working. if apply any static width and it is not effected in  application

Comment: @user2960398, can you tell me your xf version？ It works by my side，just the property defined in the pcl does not work.

Comment: This is working on mobile but it is not working on tablet

Comment: A better solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384691/masterdetailpage-in-xamarin-forms-app/48414678#48414678

Answer (score 1):

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailRenderer))]
class MyMasterDetailRenderer : MasterDetailRenderer
{
    bool firstDone;

    public override void AddView(View child)
    {
        if (firstDone)
        {
            var visualElementRenderer = this as IVisualElementRenderer;
            var element = visualElementRenderer.Element;
            MyMasterDetailPage page = (MyMasterDetailPage)element;
            LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams)child.LayoutParameters;
            p.Width = page.DrawerWidth;
            base.AddView(child, p);
        }
        else
        {
            firstDone = true;
            base.AddView(child);
        }
    }        
}
```