# MasterDetailPage in Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, master-pages, master-detail

Is it possible to create a similar side menu in `Xamarin.Forms` ?

[image]

Comment: The left side in a master detail page is just a **Vertical StackLayout**, so you can design it as you want

Comment: Refer to this repo : https://github.com/P3PPP/RightMasterDetailPageSample

Comment: thank you @OrcusZ ,@Himanshu Dwivedi , but that's not what I'm looking for, I've already seen this solution but it's not his , i search a small menu. modify a size width  to MasterPage

Answer (score 3):

> I search a small menu. modify a size width to MasterPage

You could change the width of the `Master` page in `MasterDetailPageRenderer`.

First, create a `BindableProperty` in your custom `MasterDetailPage` class:

```
public class MyMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DrawerWidthProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(
              "WidthRatio",
              typeof(int),
              typeof(MyMasterDetailPage),
              (float)0.2,
              propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
              {
              });

    public float WidthRatio
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(WidthRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WidthRatioProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Second, in your `MasterDetailPageRenderer`, set the `MyMasterDetailPage` width like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyMasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailPageRenderer))]
...
public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(oldElement, newElement);

        var width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;

        var fieldInfo = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_masterLayout", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var _masterLayout = (ViewGroup)fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        var lp = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(_masterLayout.LayoutParameters);

        MyMasterDetailPage page = (MyMasterDetailPage)newElement;
        lp.Width = (int)(page.WidthRatio * width);

        lp.Gravity = (int)GravityFlags.Left;
        _masterLayout.LayoutParameters = lp;
    }
}
```

Usage, in my `App.xaml.cs`, I set the page like this:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var mdp = new MyMasterDetailPage
    {
        Master = new MenuPage() { Title = "Master" },
        Detail = new ContentPage
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Title = "DetailPage",
            Content = new Label
            {
                Text = "DetailPage",
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            },
        },
        WidthRatio = 0.5f,
    };
    MainPage = mdp;
}
```

## Update:

About `Xamarin.iOS`, you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525241/editing-and-using-the-xamarin-forms-source-code/48559533#48559533), inspired by [P3PPP's project](https://github.com/P3PPP/RightMasterDetailPageSample), the only thing you need do is change this line in [MyPhoneMasterDetailRenderer.cs](https://github.com/P3PPP/RightMasterDetailPageSample/blob/master/iOS/MyPhoneMasterDetailRenderer.cs#L264):

```
//Change 0.8 to whatever you want
masterFrame.Width = (int)(Math.Min(masterFrame.Width, masterFrame.Height) * 0.8);
```

Comment: Couldn't get this solution to work in Xamarin Forms 5

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the built in master/detail slide out page, as it is too wide and cannot be resized easily, you could probably use the slide over kit.

It is a free open source component that should allow you to do what you need.

[Slide Over Kit details here](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/)

[image]