# Editing and using the Xamarin.Forms source code

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I was wondering if it was possible to edit the [Xamarin.Forms source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) and then use the edited one like you normally would in your xamarin.forms project.

Basically, my goal would be to change the [PhoneMasterDetailRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PhoneMasterDetailRenderer.cs) in order to change the width value of the Master page. (It is a percentage of the screen, which is **0.8**, and so by changing that it should adjust the size of the master?)

Here is the section of code I wish to change:

```
    void LayoutChildren(bool animated)
    {
        var frame = Element.Bounds.ToRectangleF();
        var masterFrame = frame;
        masterFrame.Width = (int)(Math.Min(masterFrame.Width, masterFrame.Height) * 0.8);

        ...
    }
```

The issue of not being able to change the width of the master has been a problem for a very long time, and hopefully this may lead to a solution.

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: Although you could do it, I would highly discourage it and find some other way. If you have to update Forms at some point in time you will have to apply your fix again or update the sources altogether. Why can't you implement something in a custom renderer?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking that exact same thing, but I have tried everything, and this seems to be the last thing left... I have looked everywhere and noone else has come up with a solution as well.

Comment: Since the file you want to update is a renderer, you should be able to fork just that file, make your updates, and add it as a renderer to your project. You'll want to make sure you start with the same version of the file as the version of Forms you're using, and of course you've got the update issues that Gerald mentions, but at least your exposure is limited to just that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend you to edit the source code. But we can also create our own MasterDetailPage's Renderer. It may be a little difficult, let's do this step by step.

Firstly, define a `BindableProperty` in our own `MasterDetailPage` class like:

```
public readonly static BindableProperty WidthRatioProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("WidthRatio",
            typeof(float),
            typeof(MyMasterDetailPage),
            (float)0.2);

public float WidthRatio
{
    get
    {
        return (float)GetValue(WidthRatioProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(WidthRatioProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Secondly, try to create our own renderer instead of using the form's default renderer. I post my source code [here](https://github.com/lt0526/MasterDetailRendererDemo.git) about my own renderer. In this class I use `widthRatio` changing the master's width. This property can be set in:

```
void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    else if(e.PropertyName == "WidthRatio")
    {
        widthRatio = ((MyMasterDetailPage)Element).WidthRatio;
    }
}
```

At last, create the custom renderer inheriting the renderer above like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyMasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailPageRenderer))]
namespace MasterDetailDemo.iOS
{
    public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MyPhoneMasterDetailRenderer
    {
    }
}
```

You can set the property `WidthRatio`'s value in forms's `MasterDetailPage` to change the width now. You can run my demo to test it.

Besides if you want to do this on Android, please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414678/8354952).

Comment: Hello, and thank you so much for this absolutely incredible answer! I cannot thank you enough for your help! There was a slight issue however, when a user would "swipe to reveal" the menu (when the menu is closed, swipe left anywhere on the current page), as it was possible to swipe further than expected and cover the Detail. I fixed this by removing the UpdatePanGesture method as well as all references to the _panGesture property. This prevents users from "swiping to reveal" the master, but that is perfectly okay, as they can easily reveal it by clicking on the menu icon. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my code fixing this issue. And you can try it on iPad, this renderer makes iPad has same feature like iPhone.

Comment: I just checked now, and it works absolutely perfectly, thank you very much! :)