# How to Create the slideout menu like AKSidemenu in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, hybrid

I am new to Xamarin forms. I want to create a slideout menu like AKSidemenu and below screenshot image. Kindly give me an idea for this concept.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvU1D.png]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Master Detail page

Comment: i tried but its not show like below image effect.

Comment: okay I think you do not want drawer over the content page is it the question you need custom rendering

Comment: yes I need that only

Comment: is it working now

Comment: No, I searching this above type of menu. Now  i am integrated only simple slide menu. Can you know this type tell me plz

Comment: Have you resolved the problem?

Comment: No can you know how to integrate the this type of view?

Answer (score 1):

The custom renderer is needed here.

Android
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/62894/#Comment_62894

iOS
[Editing and using the Xamarin.Forms source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525241/editing-and-using-the-xamarin-forms-source-code/48559533#48559533)