# Is there a way to both not slide the page and reduce the width of the master detail menu on Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin forms application on phone. And I try to support on ipad tablet view now. I have MasterDetailPage and I want to use masterdetail as SplitOnPortrait on ipad/tablet devices.

When I use SplitOnPortrait, Master menu takes up a lot of space. It is like following image:
[image]

So I wanted to change master detail menu width and I found this solution:

[Editing and using the Xamarin.Forms source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525241/editing-and-using-the-xamarin-forms-source-code/48559533#48559533)

https://github.com/lt0526/MasterDetailRendererDemo

It works very good. But when I use SplitOnPortrait, It slides page to right on ios/ipad like following image:
[image]

So I can't see right side on my page. I can do it on Android. But I didn't do on ios. Android is like following image:
[image]

I want to make same view on iOS. Is there a way to both not slide the page and reduce the width of the master detail menu on ios?

Comment: Hi , you can share some code about layout of current page .

Comment: I did a example project about my problem. Thank you in advance. Example project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_7s8ZasrcAi8aJObmZPukOnzpQz-vFx4/view

Comment: Thanks for sharing , if good solution will share here :)